# Running 4.5v LED string from 12v leisure battery

Tags: voltage, led, current, voltage-regulator, 12v

I have a string of 20 LEDs designed to run from 3x AA batteries in series.
I plan to hook these up to a 12v leisure battery.

Until recently I had always concentrated on getting the voltage right (supply voltage = sum of forward voltage of components) but understand there is the issue of current to consider, which is the part that confuses me slightly.

I purchased a L7805vc voltage regulator and hooked it up, the LEDs work fine but I want to ensure my maths are correct.

The problem is I have no idea what the LEDs are rated.
If I read the multimeter correctly I get 5v and 170ma which is only 8.5ma per LED?

For comparison to the 3x AA, I get 3.9v and 110ma (though they may not be brand new).

Is this fine or do I need to add a resistor somewhere, or do I need to know the LED rating to be sure?

I did try reading other questions but can't seem to find a similar enough answer to my situation.

Thanks

Comment: We need the LED rating, from the manufacturer's data sheet, to be **sure**.

Comment: What is a "leisure" battery and how does it differ from a "business" battery?

Comment: @JYelton lol ... +1

Comment: What colour is each LED, how bright do you want? And Max , Min Voltage range. For 50% brightness, use 2V for R,Y and 3V for B,W

Comment: @JYelton  don'tcha know leisure batteries are not all the same  ;)https://www.campingandcaravanningclub.co.uk/helpandadvice/technicalhelp/datasheets/guide-leisure-batteries/

Comment: If you have no idea, we have even less to go on. how about a detailed photo or weblink. The LED string may be in a matrix or array to split voltage and share current somehow.

Comment: Leisure batteries are typically the accessory batteries/12V circuit in RVs.

Answer (score 1):

These led strings do run the leds in parallel at low current per led, and typically have a resistor to keep the current in check. Simply using the 7805 would be fine, but that is higher than expected for the circuit. 3x AA batteries can be 4.8~5.2V at full charge but quickly drop down to 4.5~4.2V, their normal operating voltage range.

You could use an adjustable regulator to get a lower voltage like 4.4V or you could use a simple 1n400x diode to get a 0.7V forward drop in series with the led pack.

While the voltage and current are low, keep in mind that the 7805 is a linear regulator and while the battery is charging at 14.5 volts you are dropping 9.5V at .17 A or 1.6 Watts as heat. It will get hot. Honestly go the better route and get a cheap USB car charger. Most modern ones have switching regulators and this would be an easy to use, low power draw and low heat solution for a simple led string, compared to a linear regulator.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick responses.  A leisure battery is a lead acid type but it's a deep cycle type as opposed to a regular cat battery.  The one I have is an 88AH 12v.  The LEDs are warm white, I assume they are run in a combination of parallel and serial and not sure if there are any resistor in the circuit.  Unfortunately I have no idea what the ratings are as they are from eBay and the box they arrived in is not the original one.  The usb idea is really helpful thanks!